# Need help in creating PostgreSQL query

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a following table.

```
Name count1 Name2 count2
A    1      B     2
B    2      c     4 
A    5      C     7
```

**Name** has count1 values and **Name2** has count2 values.

I need the following result

```
a -> 6   col[0][0] + c[2][0]
b-> 4    col[0][3] + c[1][1]
c -> 11  col[1][3] + col[2][3]
```

Explanation: `B` comes in both name and name1 so we need to add both count1 and count2 for the `B`

Answer (score 1):

You need to unpivot the data and then aggregate.  Here is a simple method:

```
select name, sum(cnt)
from ((select name1 as name, count1 as cnt from t) union all
      (select name2, count2 from t)
     ) t
group by name;
```

More recent versions of Postgres support lateral joins.  These can be more efficient when you have a large amount of data, but `union all` also works fine.

EDIT:

A lateral join is very similar:

```
select v.name, sum(v.cnt)
from t, lateral join
     (values (t.name1, t.count1), (t.name2, t.count2)) v(name, cnt)
group by v.name;
```

Comment: Yes my data is very large. Please help me in lateral join solution.